# matplotlib: How to use Arial-font for legend und LaTeX-mathfont for xlabel und ylabel

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I want to set Arial for Legend and figure title， LaTeX math-font for x- and y-label.

Case 1： not using `rcParams['text.usetex'] = True`

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
legend_font = {'family' : 'Arial', 'weight' : 'normal', 'size': 23}

a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [1, 2, 3]

plt.plot(a, b, label="Legend")
plt.xlabel(r"$f/MHz$")
plt.legend(prop=legend_font)
plt.show()
```

[image]

The legend-font can be to Arial, but the font of xlabel looks ugly.

Case 2： using `rcParams['text.usetex'] = True`

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

matplotlib.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True


a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [1, 2, 3]

plt.plot(a, b, label="Legend")
plt.xlabel(r"$f/MHz$")
legend_font = {'family' : 'Arial', 'weight' : 'normal', 'size': 23}
plt.legend(prop=legend_font)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Now the font of xlabel is right. But the font for Legend no more working.

How can I solve it?

Thank you ll in Advance

Comment: I guess the optimal solution here pretty much depends on whether you want to use `tex` or whether you just want a serif math font and also how you want the rest of the ticklabels to appear.

Comment: I want both. ^-^ @ImportanceOfBeingErnest

Comment: So case 2 is what you are looking for, except for the legend? (I'm just asking because typesetting units in math mode is commonly considered bad style.)

Comment: you are right, I just want to use latex rendering for number und math. Other text like title und Legend I want to keep use Arial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following line after `plt.xlabel()` and before `legend_font = {'family' : 'Arial', 'weight' : 'normal', 'size': 23}` in your **Case 2** code (second code you wrote above)

```
matplotlib.style.use('classic')
```

**Output**

[image]